# Java Regex needed

Tags: java, regex

I need regex that will fail only for below patterns and pass for everything else.

1. RXXXXXXXXXX (X are digits)
2. XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX (IP address)

I have basic knowledge of regex but not sure how to achieve this one.

For the first part, I know how to use regex to not start with R but how to make sure it allows any number of digits except 10 is not sure.

^[^R][0-9]{10}$ - it will do the !R thing but not sure how to pull off the not 10 digits part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, simply define a regex:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("R[0-9]{10} ((0|1|)[0-9]{1,2}|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))(\\.((0|1|)[0-9]{1,2}|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))){3}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(theStringToMatch);
if(!m.matches()) {
    //do something, the test didn't pass thus ok
}
```

Or a [jdoodle](http://jdoodle.com/a/6j).

---

**EDIT**:

Since you actually wanted two possible patterns to filter out, chance the pattern to:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(R[0-9]{10})|(((0|1|)[0-9]{1,2}|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))(\\.((0|1|)[0-9]{1,2}|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))){3})");
```

If you want to match the entire string (so that the string should start and end with the pattern, place `^` in from and `$` at the end of the pattern.

Comment: Similar to @Szymon, `"R1234567890 999.999.999.999"` matches and the last part is not a valid IP (v4) address =\

Comment: Not anymore :P Modified it using different tracks.

Comment: Then why does the jdoodle works? Of course you need to specify a string to match...

Comment: It's returning false for R1234567890 as well as R123456789. I am looking for Not operator here.

Comment: After your last edit when changed `Compile` to `compile`, it worked :P

Comment: @Pankaj: there is no not operator in java, which is sad because it's a perfectly described operator for regular expressions. And it is logical that `R123456789` passes, It doesn't follow the the pattern.

Comment: Sorry, my question didn't posted both examples in different lines and caused confusion. I have two set of patterns to invalidate and rest all should be valid.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
!(string.matches("R\d{10}|(\d{3}\\.){3}\d{3}");
```

The \d means any digit, the brackets mean how many times it is repeated, and the \. means the period character.  Parentheses indicate a grouping.

Here's a good reference on java regex with examples.
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Answer (score -1):

Regex is not meant to validate every kind of input. You could, but sometimes it is not the right approach (similar to use a wrench as a hammer: it could do it but is not meant for it).

Split the string in two parts, by the space, then validate each:

```
String foo = "R1234567890 255.255.255.255";
String[] stringParts = foo.split(" ");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[^R][0-9]{10}$");
Matcher m = p.macher(stringParts[0]);
if (m.matches()) {
    //the first part is valid
    //start validating the IP
    String[] ipParts = stringParts.split("\\.");
    for (String ip : ipParts) {
        int ipPartValue = Integer.parseInt(ip);
        if (!(ipPartValue >= 0 && ipPartValue <= 255)) {
            //error...
        }
    }
}
```